# Use function argument to declare which column to use from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have an argument in a function that determines which column from a table to use in the function. The table looks like below, but could in the future have more than two different sets/columns of limits.

[image]

Is this possible? Could I use the varchar argument like LimitsTable.@MyVarcharArg? (I know that syntax wouldn't work)

Comment: No you can't do this, not without dynamic SQL, which you **cannot** use in user defined functions. This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) to me.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks! Regarding XY Problem, how would you solve the issue?

Comment: "can't" may be a little pessimistic.   There are non-Dynamic SQL methods available but they would be expensive in regards to performance.

Comment: I used "can't" as the OP implies that more values will be added in the future, @JohnCappelletti , and thus a solution not using dynamic SQL would be "broken" as soon as a new value is added to the table (or one is deleted/changed) as the function is out of date. So though you could write a static solution, it wouldn't scale.

Comment: @Larnu As you can see the function provided below is agnostic.... any table... any column.        Performant ?  Perhaps not.  Flexible?  I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I was alluding to.

As I mentioned in the comments, this can get expensive

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[Col1] decimal(10,2),[Col2] decimal(10,2),[Col3] decimal(10,2))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,1.0,null,null)
,(2,0.05,0.10,.15)
,(3,0.05,0.10,.15)
 

Select A.ID
      ,B.* 
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-JSON-GetCol](concat('Col',ID),(Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) ) B
```

** Not Clear on the Column Selection Criteria, so I simply concat `'Col' and ID`

**Results**

```
ID  Value
1   1.00
2   0.10
3   0.15
```

The TVF if Desired

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-JSON-GetCol](@col varchar(150),@json varchar(max))

Returns Table 
As Return

Select Value = JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.'+@col)
```

**EDIT - Just for Fun, it could be as simple as:**

```
Select A.ID
      ,Value = JSON_VALUE((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ),'$.'+concat('Col',ID))
 From  @YourTable A
```

2016 requires a literal key name while 2017+ can be dynamic.